# not able to publish asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, .net-4.5

I've designed a website using ASP.NET web-forms in visual studio 2013, i published the website using BUILD-> Publish selection and i used FTP publish method. 
publishing was successful , but when i type website address the following error happens :

[image: ERROR]

and this is my web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->

 <configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
< /system.web>
```

please help me to run my webstie.

UPDATE: modification to web.config file has been done as the screen says, 
after that this error happended: 
[image]

UPDATE: after targeting to .NET framework 4.0 this error happens :
[image]

Comment: This could be caused by almost anything. Follow the instructions on the screen.

Comment: First of all do what the screen tells you. Modify the web.config as it says in order for you to get a more descriptive error message. Then put this message here to help you.

Comment: but my website works on localhost

Comment: It doesnt really matter. Add the lines in web.config and you will see yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your localhost has 4.5 installed and your project targets .NET 4.5.

Install .NET framework 4.5 to your server, or target your project in .NET 4.0 provided that your server has .NET 4.0 installed.

Follow this link to see how you can change the target framework for your project : [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Comment: how to target project to .net framework 4.o in visual studio ?

Comment: Go to the properties of your project. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx i will put it in the answer

Comment: tnx , now should i publish all the files again ?

Comment: Yeap, delete the folder in you IIS and upload again.

Comment: is it IIS installed on the remote server ? where can i get all this info?

Comment: Just publish again as you did in the first time.

Comment: the problem still persists after changing the target to .net framework 4.0

Comment: you mean that now he complains even for .NET 4.0? Where r u uploading? i mean what are the specs of the server which IIS version you have? Please update your post to help you

Comment: He now cannot find the requested url. Are you sure you uploaded everything in your server?

Comment: yes visual studio did that , i think he looks for default.aspx and i uploaded that

Comment: make sure you upload everything....do you have desktop access to server or only ftp or something>?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have configured the IIS application pool to use the correct version of the .NET framework.

If you do not have `4.5` there you have to install it.

If you can try downgrading to like 4.0 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime Error

**Description:** An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

**Details:** To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

**Notes:** The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```